# <ui:inputText /> cannot get aura:id

Tags: lightning-aura-components, aura, aura-id

I have the following input in my component:

```
<ui:inputNumber class="slds-input" aura:id="thisInput" value="{!v.thisVal}" change="{!c.inputChange}"/>
```

which calls the following controller:

```
inputChange: function(c, e, h){
    var localId = event.getSource().getLocalId();
    var field=component.find(localId);
    ...
}
```

Everything was fine for months. Today I started getting the following error:

> Something has gone wrong. Action failed:
>   c$MyComponentl$controller$inputChange[TypeError: Cannot read property
>   'get' of undefined] Failing descriptor:
>   {c$MyComponent$controller$inputChange}. Please try again. Looking at
>   localId, it is returning undefined.

If I switch from an inputNumber to an inputText, there is no issue:

```
<ui:inputNumber class="slds-input" aura:id="thisInput" value="{!v.thisVal}" change="{!c.inputChange}"/>
```

Error

```
<ui:inputText class="slds-input" aura:id="thisInput" value="{!v.thisVal}" change="{!c.inputChange}"/>
```

Good

Any thoughts as to why this is happening?

Answer (score 1):

This is a combination of issues:

- I am seeing a flurry of access control exceptions in the javascript
  console:

  WARNING: Access Check Failed! AttributeSet.get(): attribute 'thisVal'
  of component 'markup://dutchdevde:inputNumberIssue {1:2;a}' is not
  visible to 'markup://dutchdevde:inputNumberIssue {1:2;a}'.
  aura_proddebug.js:16420 WARNING: Access Check Failed!
  AttributeSet.get(): attribute 'thisVal' of component
  'markup://dutchdevde:inputNumberIssue {1:2;a}' is not visible to
  'markup://dutchdevde:inputNumberIssue {1:2;a}'.
- a bug in ui:inputNumberLibrary.initialize() that I will notify the team that owns that functionality of.

Comment: Was this bug in ui:inputNumber resolved? I still face the same issue - when trying to access `event.getSource().getLocalId()` it throws an exception. After switching to ui:inputText or lightning:input it works.