# How to get aura Id of the inputNumber element in change event Handler?

Tags: javascript, lightning-aura-components

Here is the code for my problem:

**HelloWorldApp.app**

```
<aura:application >
    <c:inputNumberExample/>
</aura:application>
```

**inputNumberExample.cmp**

```
<aura:component>
    <ui:inputNumber aura:id="one-id" 
                    class="slds-input" 
                    value="2"
                    change="{!c.fldChanged}">
    </ui:inputNumber>
    <ui:outputNumber aura:id="one-id-op" 
                     value="1"
                     class="slds-hide">
    </ui:outputNumber>
</aura:component>
```

**inputNumberExampleController.js**

```
({
    fldChanged : function(component, event, helper) {
        console.log('Quantity field changed');
        console.log(component.getLocalId()); //prints undefined.
        var auraId = event.getSource().getLocalId(); 
        console.log(auraId); //prints undefined.
        var oldValue = component.find(auraId + '_OP').get("v.value");
        var newValue = component.find(auraId).get("v.value");
        console.log(oldValue);
        console.log(newValue);
    }
})
```

How do I get the `aura:id` attribute of the `ui:inputNumber` element inside event handler?

What I am trying to do is get the id of the element and append '-op' to it and locate the `ui:outputNumber` element and compare the values to see if the value changed?

Comment: are trying to have a common method for ui:inputNumber which is tied to a property to compare the old and new values?

Comment: @Praveen Yes, What I am trying is have a event handler which gets fired every time a value changed on the ui:inputNumber element and then in the event handler, I get the hidden output number and compare the values and proceed further.

Comment: won't copying the whole object(one you are dealing with which has an aura:attribute for it) into another aura:attribute in the beginning and comparing the values of the property binded to ui:inputNumber(lets say original's X) with the copied object's X won't work in your case?
Eg:
`<ui:outputNumber aura:id="one-id-op" 
                     value="{!v.original.x}"
                     class="slds-hide">
 var original = cmp.get("v.original"), copy = cmp.get("v.copied") //contains copy of the original object used in view;
console.log(original.x == copy.x)`

Comment: But it works only if you have separate change handler attached for each and every ui:inputNumber you wanted to check on.

Comment: All this is happening inside aura:iteration so I guess what you suggested won't work right? My lightning skills are very poor. so please suggest if there are better alternatives.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I ran into that issue as well.

Could not get it to work using *aura:id*, so I used the good old 'id', HTML tags and JavaScript instead.

**Component**

```
<aura:component access="global" >
    <input type="text" id="one-id" class="slds-input" onchange="{!c.inputChanged}" />

    <input type="text" id="one-id-op" class="slds-input" value="1" readonly="true"/>
</aura:component>
```

I have used *type="text"* and *onchange* event for demo. purposes. Please change accordingly.

**Controller.js**

```
({
     inputChanged : function(component, event, helper) {
        var input = event.target.id; //this is = one-id
        var inputValue = document.getElementById(input).value;
        var output = document.getElementById(input + "-op");
        var outputValue = output.value;

        console.log('inputValue : ', inputValue);
        console.log('outputValue : ', outputValue);
    }
})
```

Comment: One other option is to user ui:Inputtext / ui:outputtext and add validations around to prevent string input. getlocalId seems to work with XXXtext not with XXXnumber http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/127152/uiinputtext-cannot-get-auraid

Comment: I thought using `ui` namespace elements solves problems but it is causing more headaches :( My journey just started with lightning.

Comment: Great! I just tried this and it is working.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find the aura:id here:

event.source.Rc.rc

Then you can do:

`var fieldId = event.source.Rc.rc;
var val = component.find(field).get("v.value");`

I cannot believe that Lightning has so many stupid bugs like this one...